# When will the conection open to database in telerik ORM Entity models ?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, telerik, telerik-open-access

When context object is initialized or when linq query is fired on the context object ? 
I have one window service that create the threads to update my database tables Each thread make calls to different class which in case create the context object and update the data.
I have called the dispose() method on the context object but it didn't close the connection.

I have to limit the connection any how
Please advice

Answer (score 0):

By default, Telerik Data Access uses its own connection pool. With it, the connections are obtained in four cases:

1. when you evaluate a LINQ query,
2. when you call the Add method of the context,
3. when you call the SaveChanges method of the context, and
4. when you use the GetObjectByKey method.

When the context instance is disposed, the connections are returned to the pool rather than disposed. The piling up of connections with the Data Access connection pool is possible in scenarios like breaking the reading process before all the results are returned but in general it depends on the specifics on your side.

To troubleshoot the case on your side, you could test your application with the [ADO Connection Pool](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/feature-reference/tools/model-settings-dialog/backend-settings/feature-ref-tools-visual-designer-model-settings-backend-conn-pool). It is possible that in your scenario, this is the more performant option.